# accessing constructor name from prototype function in javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype, function-prototypes

Is it possible to do the following:

```
function A() {}
function B() {}
B.prototype = A;
function C() {}
C.prototype = A;

A.prototype.myname = function() { /* get 'B' or 'C' here */ }
```

so that when I for example call B.myname() I will have the name 'B' available in the function body?

Trying `this.constructor.name` as expected just returns 'A' every time.

Comment: why don't you check it by yourself?

Comment: How do you mean? What I actually want to do is customize the method so that it will behave differently depending on how it is called.

Comment: Your function declarations have syntax errors, remove the `=`! Then, Why use a function as the prototype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're looking for this?

```
function A() {}
A.prototype.myname = function() {
    return this.constructor.name;   
};
function B() {}
B.prototype = new A();
B.prototype.constructor = B;
var b = new B();
console.log(b.myname()); // logs B
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BFxnb/